# When I add a lot of records into JavaDB, it becomes very sluggish

Tags: javadb

Do I have to index it? But How do I keep it consistent with the main table. I heard about re-indexing, but when do I do a re-index where appropriate?
Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is becoming sluggish? The inserts? In this case adding an index is probably not going to help. You could look for bulk insert in the docs.

If queries against the large table are getting slow, it may help with an index? If, or how much it helps, depends on how your table is defined and how you access it.

To create an index consult CREATE INDEX statement in the ref manual. It is kept consistent with base table automatically.